# Is it a must to synchronize ConsumerRecords when I only want to concurrnetly read it?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Firest I poll data from kafka and need to read the records using asynchronized methods, I'm puzzled if it is thread safe to access the consumerRecords?

The code snippets go as following:

```
ConsumerRecords<String,String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
//1. asynchronously read topic1
foo.asynMethod1(consumerRecords(topic1));
//2. asynchronously read topic2
bar.asynMethod2(consumerRecords(topic2));
```

Comment: Those records are iterable, so you'd have to make a copy or dump to a list to not increment the same iterator in both methods

Comment: @cricket_007 even when i deal with different topics in two methods?

Comment: As long as you are using the same iterable object, then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you *don't write* to a piece of data, and that data is *already populated* by the time readers begin execution, you will **not** get any data races from reading that data concurrently, provided that the reference by which the readers refer to the data remains unchanged.

tl;dr: As you've specified it in your code fragment, no.